# Keep wifi connected after log off

Tags: macos, wifi, airport

Is there a way to maintain a wifi connection after log off on OS X 10.8 Lion?

I would like to be able to log in, log off, and log into a new account on my domain without having to plug in my ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

Set `DisconnectOnLogout=NO`:

```
sudo /Sy*/L*/Priv*/Apple8*/V*/C*/R*/airport en1 prefs DisconnectOnLogout=NO
```

<sup>Replace `en1` with the interface number of your AirPort card, if it's different.</sup>

Comment: I've tried this....the command goes through but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Pickle Have you rebooted?

Comment: Yes.  This network requires a certificate, which the laptop has, if that has anything to do with it.